# Adding additional claims to a token after authentication for additional services

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, jwt, bearer-token

Imagine a scenario where a desktop application calls a Single Sign On service to log the current user in. This service authenticates the user and returns a token (a Json Web Token) which is signed with the private part of a public/private key pair. This token has some claims about the identity of the user.

The application then wishes to call a different service for some data and so passes on the token to the service. The service uses the claims in the token (and the fact that it was signed by the SSO service) to identify the current user and to determine which data to return. So far so good.

Now say the application wants to provide some additional pieces of information which are not related to the identity of the user but some context about the current session the user is using in the application (like the current database they are connected to).

These seem like good candidates for additional claims which can be sent with the request, so the data service can extract the claims from the token and use both the identity claims from the SSO and the application specific claims from the desktop application to decide what to do and how to do it. (like which database to update)

The issue is that we can't add claims to the existing token as this has been signed by the SSO service and the application can't know the private key to sign the new token. If the original token is not present then the data service can't trust that the identity came from the SSO, so can't allow access to the data at all.

Options I can think of:

- After authentication the application calls the SSO service again providing a collection of claims (secured in some way, not just anyone can call the SSO to get additional claims added to the token) and the SSO token, and the SSO service returns a new token which contains the identity claims and the additional claims the application wants to add
- The application creates a new token which it signs and one of the claims in this token is to original token the SSO service provided.

Both of these have pros and cons, but on balance I think I prefer the first option.

To complicate things a little more, there is not just one 'application' there are a few. All will use the same SSO service, and all will want to add some additional application specific claims (ie the claims for app1 and app2 will be different)

Is there an out of the box solution for this problem already? Or are there other ways of dealing with this issue then the options outlined above?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I like either option.

> After authentication the application calls the SSO service again
>   providing a collection of claims and the SSO token, and the SSO
>   service returns a new token which contains the identity claims and the
>   additional claims the application wants to add

I don't think any SSO service will allow you to do this. The claims in the token are signed as the SSO service guarantees they are correct. If the SSO service would start signing arbitrary data, that guarantee no longer holds.

> The application creates a new token which it signs and one of the
>   claims in this token is to original token the SSO service provided.

If you let your application sign access tokens, you'll have to distribute the public keys of both the SSO service and the application. And your data service now has to trust both.

Why not just pass this extra info the data service may need as parameters in the service call? If you are calling the service over HTTPS, the integrity of whatever you pass is guaranteed.

Comment: There are a few different applications (all owned by us) which will use the SSO service and call the data service, but each will pass different pieces of data about its current context. These pieces of data will be relevant when so future message is created by the data service and handled by some other service, where the claims in the token would be used. They are meta data, rather than parameters in the service call. I excluded this from the original question to avoid over complicating things.

Comment: The additional claims could be signed by the applications to allow the SSO to trust that the claims it is sent are from one of the applications that is allowed to ask for claims to be added. this would allow all service to trust only the SSO, not every application, and only the SSO would need to know about the other applications. I didn't image that 'anyone' could ask the SSO to add claims to the token, and apologies if that came across in the question

Comment: Thanks for the answer though. I've updated the question to clarify both of these points

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I don't know of any STS that will let applications specify claims to include. ADFS can issue claims from a SQL database and can have different claim sets per relying party (application). Of course if you build your own, you can do whatever you want, but you should preferably not build your own security infrastructure.